# AVPlayerItem Duration Incorrect When AVCaptureMovieFileOutput Records Both Video and Audio

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, avcapturesession

I have an `AVCaptureSession` running a live preview. I setup both video and audio `AVCaptureDeviceInput`'s to record to a single `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` as follows:

```
private void ConfigureSession(AVCaptureSession session) {
    session.BeginConfiguration();

    // setup camera input
    var cameraDevice = AVCaptureDevice.GetDefaultDevice(AVCaptureDeviceType.BuiltInWideAngleCamera, AVMediaType.Video, AVCaptureDevicePosition.Back);
    cameraDevice = cameraDevice ?? AVCaptureDevice.GetDefaultDevice(AVMediaType.Video);

    var captureDeviceInput = AVCaptureDeviceInput.FromDevice(cameraDevice);

    if (session.CanAddInput(captureDeviceInput)) {
        session.AddInput(captureDeviceInput);
    }

    // setup mic input
    var microphoneDevice = AVCaptureDevice.GetDefaultDevice(AVMediaType.Audio);
    var microphoneInput = AVCaptureDeviceInput.FromDevice(microphoneDevice);

    if (session.CanAddInput(microphoneInput)) {
        session.AddInput(microphoneInput);
    }

    // setup single output
    var output = new AVCaptureMovieFileOutput();
    output.MaxRecordedDuration = new CMTime(5 * 600, 600);  // max of 5 seconds
    if (session.CanAddOutput(output)) {
        session.AddOutput(output);
    }

    session.CommitConfiguration();

}
```

At this point my session is already running. As you can see, the video and audio inputs are added, along with a single output.

The output also has a `MaxRecordedDuration` of 5 seconds. After 5 seconds of recording the `output` automatically stops. I then load the resulting video file in an `AVPlayerItem`, and add it to an `AVPlayer` for playback:

```
    private AVPlayer SetupPlayer(string videoFilePath) {
        var asset = AVAsset.FromUrl(NSUrl.FromFilename(videoFilePath));
        var playableKey = "playable";

        var playerItem = new AVPlayerItem(asset, new NSString[] { (NSString)playableKey, (NSString)"hasProtectedContent" });
        playerItem.AddObserver(this, "status", NSKeyValueObservingOptions.OldNew, IntPtr.Zero);

        var player = AVPlayer.FromPlayerItem(playerItem);

        return player;
    }

    public override void ObserveValue(NSString keyPath, NSObject ofObject, NSDictionary change, IntPtr context) {
        if (keyPath == "status") {
            PlayerItemStatusChanged(new NSObservedChange(change));
        } else {
            base.ObserveValue(keyPath, ofObject, change, context);
        }
    }

    private void PlayerItemStatusChanged(NSObservedChange change) {
        AVPlayerItemStatus status = (AVPlayerItemStatus)Convert.ToInt32(change.NewValue.ToString());

        switch (status) {
            case AVPlayerItemStatus.Unknown:
                break;
            case AVPlayerItemStatus.ReadyToPlay:
                Debug.WriteLine($"Ready to Play: Player Item Duration: {Player.CurrentItem.Duration}");
                break;
            case AVPlayerItemStatus.Failed:
                // TODO: show error
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

When the `Status` is changed my observer is hit, which prints to the console the `Duration`. The duration here, however, always outputs around `5.6` seconds, instead of `5` seconds as defined by the movie file output's `MaxRecordedDuration`.

When I remove the microphone input, the duration outputted by the `AVPlayerItem` becomes `5`.

Why would recording audio in addition to video cause the `AVPlayerItem`'s duration to shift? The overall duration outputted by the movie file output object is always `5`, with or without audio.

Comment: Suggest that using manual start-recording/stop-recording technique (instead of Maximmum Time logic) using a timer and some flags.

Comment: I happen to give that a try after posting this. Manually stopping via a timer gives closer to accurate results, but still an increment occurs. When I force the output to stop and check the `RecordedDuration` property it outputs around `4.5 seconds` (with a timer set to 5 seconds). When I load that video via the AVPlayer/ AVPlayerItem, the `Duration` is always around `5.1 seconds`. That's a `0.6 second` difference in what the output "RecordedTime" stated vs what the player finds. Regardless of whether I use `MaxRecordedDuration` or a timer, the `AVPlayerItem` always has a higher count.